# Passing NULL to SQL Server with ANSI_NULLS = ON

Tags: python, sql-server, pyodbc

Hoping for some guidance.

The SQL Server stored procedure will write and commit new records with NULL values passed when executed directly via SSMS.

```
DECLARE @return_value int
EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[WP_InsertNewCrypto]
        @CryptoID = NULL,
        @Crypto_name = NULL,
        @Crypto_Link_WP = NULL,
        @Crypto_Launched = NULL,
        @Crypto_Token = N'0x'
SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value
```

`CryptoID` is defined as a unique identifier/GUID in the table and the stored procedure generates `NewID()` if it needs to CREATE a new record.

Switching to the Python script - using a vanilla pyodbc as a trusted connection, the connection works and returns a value when querying the system table for the version number of SQL Server.

```
def WriteSQLRecord (C1, C2, C3, C4, C5):
    connection = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=DESKTOP;DATABASE=DBNAME;Trusted_Connection=yes;')
    cursor=connection.cursor()
    storedProc = "Exec [dbo].[WP_InsertNewCrypto] @CryptoID = ? , @Crypto_Name  = ?, @Crypto_Link_WP = ?, @Crypto_Launched = ?, @Crypto_Token =?"
    
#params = (None, None,None,None,C5) 
    #params = (NULL, NULL,NULL,NULL,C5) 
    #params = (myUUID, NULL,NULL,NULL,C5) 
    # Execute Stored Procedure With Parameters
    cursor.execute( storedProc, params )
    cursor.close()  
    del cursor
    connection.close()
```

However, the target stored procedure when executed fails to result in the new record being written.

SQL Server Profiler shows the script as

```
declare @p1 int
set @p1=1
exec sp_prepexec @p1 output,
N'@P1 varchar(1),
@P2 varchar(1),
@P3 varchar(1),
@P4 varchar(1),
@P5 nvarchar(4)',
N'Exec [dbo].[WP_InsertNewCrypto] 
@CryptoID = @P1 , 
@Crypto_Name  = @P2, 
@Crypto_Link_WP = @P3, 
@Crypto_Launched = @P4, 
@Crypto_Token =@P5',
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
N'0x'
select @p1
```

I pass the null values from python as NULL.

I generate an empty GUID variable for the parm and I have also passed it as NULL via a string and integer.

I dutifully open and close the connection at beginning and end of the  execution as well as closing and deleting the cursor.

Scratching head. I cannot be the first person to try and pass NULLS to a UniqueIdentifier or NULLS to a SQL Server stored procedure.
:-)

Comment: FYI the syntax `'literl string alias' = {expression}` is deprecated and should be avoided. Or, better yet, just don't use literal strings for aliaes at all.

Comment: Please show your Python code and relevant stored procedure

Comment: Are you using `autocommit=True` or are you calling `conn.commit()` explicitly?

Comment: @Charlieface PYTHON code

Comment: Try adding `connection.commit()` before `connection.close()`